# How to deploy odoo on OpenShift?

Tags: python, git, postgresql, openshift, odoo

I'm a bit confused with Openshift... so far i've created an app and added **python and postgresql**, i've downloaded odoo-master from sourceforge, and what i've done is clone the git, then what do i have to do?, should i just copy the folder odoo-master into the folder that git created, then run `"git add ."->"git commit -m"odoo added" "->"git push"` ?

Another questions that i have are:

- When i add a new folder in the app folder how do i tell openshift to run the files that are inside that folder?
- What does OpenShift Origin is?(be clear for a newbie)
- What can i do with OpenShift Cartridge?
- Is cartridge a client tool?, what are the client tools and what are they for?

If the question is unclear please ask me, my native language is not english and my technical language is not too great.

Answer (score 3):

I can answer some of the questions.

**Openshift origin**

This is the primary place for Openshift source code. You will get all the features quickly in origin. After a lot of formal QA, the source is moved to enterprise and online. But in the end, the features you see in Openshift Origin should end in Online and Entreprise, as that's the same codebase. You can run the origin in your local system like a docker image in Virtual machine.

**OpenShift-Specific Terminology**

**Application**

This is your typical web application that will run on OpenShift. At this time, OpenShift is focused on hosting web applications. In your case it is Odoo (Openerp).

**Gear**

A gear is a server container with a set of resources that allows you to run their applications. Your gears run on OpenShift in the cloud. There are currently three gear types on OpenShift Online: small, medium, and large. Each size provides 1 GB of disk space by default. The large gear has 2 GB of RAM, the medium gear has 1 GB of RAM, and the small and small.highcpu gears have 512 MB of RAM.

**Cartridge**

To get a gear to do anything, you need to add a cartridge. Cartridges are the plug-ins that house the framework or components that can be used to create and run an application.

Basically Openshift splitted their runtime environments through different cartridges. Cartridges can be web frameworks, databases, monitoring services, or connectors to external backends. In the case of odoo, you need python and postgresql cartridges.

Python is a **Standalone** cartridge, postgresql is a **Embedded** cartridge.

You can control your cloud environment through the OpenShift Client tools, known as [rhc](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-client-tools.html) or [Web console](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console).

With rhc, it easy to create and deploy applications, manage domains, control access to your OpenShift applications, and give you complete control of your cloud environment. Consider this as a ssh client for your openshift server.

You need to install Odoo dependencies from the openshift temp data directory in order to run Odoo (I have not tried Odoo in Openshift yet).

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! almost everything i asked is covered, the only thing missing is how to deploy the app, do i just add Odoo files to git repo then access to my app and wait for it to work? other thing is that Odoo need some python dependencies but how do i tell Openshift through rhc to install them?